# Working with percents in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a site with a fluid layout, and therefore need to use percentages in my Jquery sizes and animations. The problem, as I've discovered, is that Jquery doesn't understand percentages. Here's an example of what I'm after:

The page `<body>` is 100% wide.

`<article>` is the width of 71% of the page body.

`<hgroup>` is the width of 33.2% of `<article>`

I would like `<article>` to be the same width as `<hgroup>` on page load (so that only `<hgroup>` is showing), then expand to 71% of the page width again when `<hgroup>` is clicked, allowing the rest of the content within `<article>` to show. At the same time, I'd like `<article>` to slide left by the width of `<hgroup>`, hiding `<hgroup>`.

Is there any way to make this kind of calculation, or will I have to resort to pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much frustration and lamentation, I finally got it sorted out. Here's the code I came up with which, miraculously, works:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('section').hide();
            //Capture widths on page load
            var bwidth = $('body').width();
            var awidth = $('article').width();
            var hgwidth = $('hgroup').width();
            $('hgroup').width(hgwidth);
            $('article').width(hgwidth);

            $('hgroup').click(function(){
            //Hide open article
            var close = $('section:visible').parent();
            $(close).children('section').hide().end().width(hgwidth);
            $(close).removeClass('active').css('marginLeft', '+=' +hgwidth).detach().appendTo('body');

            //Hide last Article
                $('body article').last().hide();

            //Show current
            $(this).parent().addClass('active')
                $('.active').animate({
                            width: awidth,
                            marginLeft: '-=' + hgwidth  
                        },500);
                $(this).next().delay(500).fadeIn(50);
                $(this).css('box-shadow','0px 0px 8px #666');

                //Show Next Hgroup
                $(this).parent().nextAll('article:first').show();

                  });
        });
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should [accept your own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65363/can-i-answer-my-own-question).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can define

```
article {
    width: 23.6%;
    /* that's 33.2% of 71% of 100 */
}

hgroup {
    width: 100%;
    /* that's in relation to article */
}
```

plus whatever positioning you need

then

```
$('article').width($('body').width() / 100 * 71);
$('hgroup').width($('article').width() / 100 * 33.2);
```

plus whatever effects you need

Comment: I wanted the articles/hgroups to be the proper size in case someone was viewing without javascript for some reason; that way, the content wouldn't vanish. I ended up capturing the width values on doc ready and storing them as variables I could use throughout the script. Thanks, though; this would've worked if I didn't need article to fallback to its proper width.

Comment: then you can set 71% width for article and 33.2% for hgroup in css which will be the fallback. Then on pageload set it to 23.6 and 100 via jquery respectively and then on click again to 71% and 33.2% as I'm describing above.

Comment: I may still go back and streamline the code with something like this now that I've gotten it working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for slide effect. Take a look at jquery ui slide effect http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide. It might help you without much coding.

Comment: The effect I'm going for is more of an accordion than a single slide, as there are three articles involved. My biggest issue is figuring out how to tell my script that I want things sized in percents; I'll nail down the effects later.